# Aliasing $scope in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm trying to create an adaptor for angular so that my services,controllers etc.. can use generic names its features, and then if I change to use another mvc library in future, or want to use my existing service in a project using an mvc with a similar feature set, I can (in theory) create an adapter for that library too and my service will work just as well

Using browserify...

#### adapter

```
module.exports = require('angular').module('adapter', [])
    .service('global', function ($rootScope) {
        return $rootScope;
    })
    .service('ajax', function ($http) {
        return $http;
    })
```

#### Module

```
var angular = require('angular');
require('adapter');

module.exports = angular.module('jnr.common', ['adapter'])

    .controller('example', require('./controller'));
```

#### Controller

```
module.exports = function(http) {
    http( ... ); 
};
```

Everything is getting injected as expected so far except for `$scope`

```
    .service('self', function ($scope) {
        return $scope;
    })
```

I keep getting a `Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- self` error. As `$scope` changes from context to context I figure I need to use some kind of getter/factory, but not sure how exactly.

Comment: I think you should put the 'self' service also under the adapter, like 'global' and 'ajax'.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be moving to another MVC architecture if you are using AngularJS. Not unless you want to rewrite all of your "glue" code, because that is what AnguarJS is, it glues everything together in it's own special angular way. Your best bet is to move all of your functionality into your own library of functions/objects and not worry about trying to duplicate angular with another framework.

That being said, $scope is only created for controllers/directives. They are semantically different form services. Controller scopes are created based on how your HTML is structured, you won't be able to "adapt" those. Services are more like singletons and have no "scope" or associated HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is `$scope` a service, that can be injected, nor do services have a scope.

`$scope` is only used by directives and it is a local variable, that is created before the postLink function of the directive is called.